# Help identifying wedding invitation font "RSVP"

Tags: font-identification

I've tried all of the font identification sites. I still can't find the name of this font. Can someone help me? I've found this on some wedding invitations and I'd like to purchase said font for creating my own invitations in the future.

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't know the font, but there are [plenty of similar fonts](https://creativemarket.com/fonts/script/popular/1) out there. Maybe you'll find one you like even better. Otherwise I'd recommend contacting whomever you got that image from to figure out the font.

Answer (score 3):

I wish I would have seen this question sooner, I used this font on a project last year. If you're still looking (6 months later), the font is [Ondise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a47iU.png).

[image]